# Sharing USB Printer Through Windows Print Server

Tags: windows, active-directory, print-server

I have Windows 2012 R2 print server which sharing network printer to AD users. Now I want share USB printer as same.

What I have done so far

1. connected USB printer to a PC. Print from PC (AD member) okay.
2. shared the printer to network. From print server its accessible.
3. Connected the shared USB printer on print server.
4. Print from print server is okay.
5. Added the printer on print management by PC IP
6. Test print from print management is not working

I think problem in step 5 & 6. Can anyone guide what might be wrong here ? how to resolve this ?

Note: The reason I want to add the shared USB printer to print server is to pull ad user's print statistics from server event log.

Comment: I've tried this in the past with my home printer, but it wasn't possible since the printer driver doesn't support to be connected to an external print server. What's the model of your printer?

Comment: @LeRouteur we have varieties of vendor and models of printers. I am checking with Lexmark MS415dn.